# json_decode returns nempty value php

Tags: php, android, json

I am getting json string from my android app that contains the data for user registration.
In server side i am using php to insert it in to database.

Here is the json string that I will get

```
{"user_name":"Steve Jobs","user_email":"steave@apple.com","user_password":"nopassword","user_phone_number":"1234567890","club_member_id":"24"}
```

But when I convert it in to an array I will get **null** value.

```
<?php

  //$_POST contains the json string. 
  $data = json_decode($_POST,true);


?>
```

`$data` will get empty string

How will I resolve it.

**UPDATE**

Content of `file_get_contents('php://input')`

> POST=%7B%22user_name%22%3A%22Steve+Jobs%22%2C%22user_email%22%3A%22steave%40apple.com%22%2C%22user_password%22%3A%22nopassword%22%2C%22user_phone_number%22%3A%221234567890%22%2C%22club_member_id%22%3A%2224%22%7

**JAVA**

```
private void onSignup() throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

//         Add your data

        try {
            jsonParams.put("user_name", "Steve Jobs");
            jsonParams.put("user_email", "steave@apple.com");
            jsonParams.put("user_password", "nopassword");
            jsonParams.put("user_phone_number", "1234567890");
            jsonParams.put("club_member_id", "24");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("POST", jsonParams.toString()));
            Log.e("mainToPost", "mainToPost" + nameValuePairs.toString());
            // Use UrlEncodedFormEntity to send in proper format which we need
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        Log.e("Data", String.valueOf(json));
        try {

            // Getting JSON Array
            JSONArray user = json.getJSONArray("POST");
            Log.e("JSON ARRAY", String.valueOf(user));
            ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0, count = user.length(); i < count; i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = user.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonObject.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    stringArray.add(name);
                    Log.e("JSON ARRAY", String.valueOf(stringArray));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
//                name1.setText(String.valueOf(stringArray));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_POST);` ? Post the results here.

Comment: which variable within $_POST did you put the JSON string into?

Comment: how are you converting it to array? can u show the code for that

Answer (score 2):

Having seen you edit, it seems you are sending the json as part of a key value pair after all, just with a weird key name (POST) which confused matters.

You should be able to get the data via:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['POST'],true);
```

For clarity, it would probably make sense to change the key name to something more sensible:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", jsonParams.toString()));
```

Then you would access via:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['json'],true);
```

Or alternativly, just send the data as json, not key value pair:

```
try {
        jsonParams.put("user_name", "Steve Jobs");
        jsonParams.put("user_email", "steave@apple.com");
        jsonParams.put("user_password", "nopassword");
        jsonParams.put("user_phone_number", "1234567890");
        jsonParams.put("club_member_id", "24");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
        httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        httppost.setEntity(params);
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    }
```

Then use the php code described below in my original answer

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

`$_POST` is an array, populated automatically when a post request is received containing key value pairs (`contentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

If you post json data (`contentType application/json`), `$_POST` will not be populated, instead you need to parse the input stream:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

your json data might comming in some array index of POST not in complete global array you code should be like this

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['some_json_field'], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['string_name_in_which_json_string_is_present'],true);
```

Comment: This will get an empty array

Answer (score 0):

you can't use $_POST to get the values. Please try:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

This should do it.

$_POST will not be populated if the request body is not in the standard urlencoded form.